# How to bind and get values for datepicker which is generated dynamically using angular4 datepicker?

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker

I'm trying hard to find a solution for this and couldn't find any. I am using this [datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular4-datepicker) to bind and get values for a datepicker that's generated dynamically. Here's what I tried so far:

```
<tr *ngFor="let rpr of DocumentMode">   
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="rpr.DOC_ATTCHE_PATH">
    </td>
    <td style="width: 18%">        
        <my-date-picker name="from" [options]="DocDatePickerOptions" [placeholder]="placeholder" [(ngModel)]="validFrom"></my-date-picker> 
    </td>   
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="rpr.SD_REMARKS">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="btnUpload1" value="Upload1" name="Selectedfiles1" (change)="fileChange($event, rpr)"
            accept=".pdf" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" [value]="rpr.IS_CHECK" [checked]="rpr.IS_CHECK" (change)="$event.target.checked ? rpr.IS_CHECK = true : rpr.IS_CHECK = false">
            </label>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here's the code snippet, on how I tried to retrieve the values sent by the JSON object.

Here's the definition:

```
public DocDatePickerOptions: IMyDpOptions = {
    dateFormat: 'yyyy.mm.dd',
    showInputField: true,
    editableDateField: true,
    showClearDateBtn: false,
    inline: false
  }
```

Here's how I tried to get and bind values for the dynamical datpicker:

```
DocDateRetreive() {
    for (var i = 0; this.DocumentMode.length; i++) {
      if (this.DocumentMode[i].SD_VALID_FROM == null) {

      }
      else {
        var validFromTemp = new Date(this.DocumentMode[i].SD_VALID_FROM);
        this.validFrom = { date: { year: validFromTemp.getFullYear(), month: validFromTemp.getMonth() + 1, day: validFromTemp.getDate() } };
        console.log("valid", this.validFrom);

      }
    }   

  }
```

So finally I call this function in `OnInit()` which get called when the page loads.

It runs but nothing happens. I get some errors for null values.

How do I correctly bind and get values? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @BhanuTejP `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'SD_VALID_FROM' of undefined` For the [0] array I get the value from the console.

Comment: can you provide plunker or stackblitz.

Comment: @BhanuTejP I don't think the datepicker is available at plunker

Comment: Create it in stackbliz. I created this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7y3i9q.

Comment: @BhanuTejP Now try and see I have pasted some code.

Comment: Hi, provide the stackblitz link.